# Parameter List in Jenkins to display list of build numbers from another build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two Jenkins builds, one for compiling and one for deploying.

The developer wants to be able to choose a build from the compiler build when running the deploy build, not always run the most recent build.

What I am after is a method of populating a choice parameter for the deploy build with a list of successful\unstable builds from the compile build.

I will then use the the option listed in the parameter to deploy that artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the [Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to mark a specific build to be deployed. This moves the choice from the deployment build into the compilation build. Select the *Promote builds when...* option in the compilation build and set up how you want promotion to work. The developer could choose (or automate) the build to promote. In the deployment build, the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) can grab the appropriate build (based on a permalink to the latest promoted build).

Comment: The use case of one deployment per build seems to be covered with this scenario. In my company we have several different dev environments that may or may not need a deployment. Also sometimes a particular build might need to be deployed more than once to a environment. I am skeptical that this scenario is covered by your solution.

Comment: @Peter, agreed. We use promoted builds for simple cases and a release procedure for publishing different builds, but we don't have the deployment complexity that you've described.

Comment: Your answer is heavily outdated.

Answer (score 11):

Using the [Dynamic Parameters plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in)

In your promote job:

- [x] This build is parameterized
- Add Parameter
- Dynamic Choice Parameter
- Set Name to whatever
- Paste below into Choices Script

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.AbstractProject
import hudson.model.Result
import hudson.util.RunList

AbstractProject<?, ?> otherJob = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("otherJobName", AbstractProject.class)
RunList<?> builds = otherJob.getBuilds().overThresholdOnly(Result.SUCCESS)

def list = builds.limit(5).collect { it.number }
```

Screenshot from wiki page:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

As [Dynamic Parameters plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) is no more accessible. You can use [Active Choice parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin in Jenkins.
Now you can list all successful Jenkins builds as parameterized option in Jenkins Job/pipeline

Follow below steps to access the list of successful jobs [as dropdown list]

1. In job configuration [General section] select this project is parameterized
2. Select add parameter as "Active choice parameter"
3. Give name for parameter
4. Select groovy script and paste below code in groovy script text box

   `return jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getJob('<Jenkins-job>').builds.findAll{ it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS }.collect{ "$it.number" }`
5. It worked awesome without without powershell and BASH
6. No need to process Jenkins API and filter JSON output

Comment: More universal version of groovy script: `return jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('<folder>/<job>').builds.findAll{ it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS }.collect{ it.displayName[1..-1] }`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to populate the choice parameter. However, you don't need to always use the newest build. I assume that you use the [copy artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). This plugin provides the "Build selector for Copy Artifact" parameter. You still need to enter the build number manually, but when deploying you have all the standard choices, like "Latest successful build", but also "Specific Build". You need to enter the number and don't have a drop down, but I got my deployers trained well enough to enter the build number.