# Jenkins - an options list with IDs from the other build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Is it possible to create an options list in Jenkins pipeline which always contains the last 50 numbers of the jobs from the other Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: can you share what is the intent of showing the last 50 build numbers in another build.

Comment: Only the last 50 builds' artifacts are stored, so I want to implement a little utility. It will protect from inserting a wrong value.

Comment: does this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135280/parameter-list-in-jenkins-to-display-list-of-build-numbers-from-another-build